# Meaning of more Kishi Bashi lyrics: けや けや それや どうせね

Tags: translation, idioms

Kishi Bashi:  ["Bright Whites"](http://www.songlyrics.com/kishi-bashi/bright-whites-lyrics/)

Transliterating from the ローマ字 lyrics, (so I don't know which kanji is meant):

> けや けや それや どうせね
>   けや けや それや どうせ だめだ
>   やめられない やめられない
>   どうせ だめだけど やめられない ね

and then a second verse with たえられない in place of やめられない.

Specifically I'm curious about the meaning of the line

> けや けや それや どうせね.

Google translate does not seem to offer a consistent translation of this, and the term けや only translates as "things like hair".  Plus the repetition seems significant.

Also, what's the nuance of どうせ (as compared with どう by itself)?

Anyway if all this is not "standard" Japanese, it's worth knowing.

Comment: けや means nothing to me. Do you know the title?

Comment: @naruto sorry, edited the question to add a link.  I have a feeling his lyrics are meant to be "poetic" translations of English phrases, and may not be natural Japanese.

Comment: From the lyrics I think what you wrote それや are actually そりゃ.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google seems to have interpreted the first line as 毛や毛や ("hairs and hairs"), which is of course nonsense.

AFAIK ケヤ means nothing. In lyrics a meaningless word that just sounds nice can appear (e.g., "la la la", "[du bi du bi du bi du du du](http://j-lyric.net/artist/a051a6d/l01a7b8.html)", "[ババンババンバンバン](http://j-lyric.net/artist/a001629/l009ffd.html)"), so ケヤ may be one of them.

どうせ is a single word that means "anyway" or "no matter what is done", and it precedes something negative/unwanted (だめ/やめられない/たえられない in this case). どう ("how") is quite different.

Comment: Thank you.  It's important to know that words like ケヤ are meaningless musical sounds.

Answer (score 0):

"どうせ" means "anyway" or "sonner or later"

"たえられない（耐えられない）" is different from "やめられない"

I'm not sure about the object of "耐えられない", in this lyrics,but generally it means "I can't suffer." or "I can't take it."

The song is probably related to male-femail relationships. So he or she can't stand being near his (her) significant other (lover), or finds himself (herself) unable to stay away drom his (her) SO.

"やめられない" generall means "I can't quit" or "I won't to be able to put it down."

In this lyrics, "やめられない" and "あきらめられない (can't let it go)" could be interchangeable with each other. The relationship might be going fall through.